# IE7 Debug Issue - Word Breaks in <li>

Tags: css, debugging, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I am having a very basic problem in IE7 that I cannot seem to fix. If you look at this page: http://vitaminjdesign.com/IAM/company/ you will notice that the vertical nav (ul id="leftcol") is displaying incorrectly in IE7. Each word appears on its own line. Here is my HTML /. CSS:

```
<ul id="leftcol">
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Company Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Why Choose Parker?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Financing Promotions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Licensing & Credentials</a></li>
</ul>

ul#leftcol{float:left; width:185px; position:relative; z-index:10;}
ul#leftcol li{float:right; clear:right; margin-bottom:14px; list-style:none; list-style-image:none; text-align:right; line-height:1.3; }
ul#leftcol li a{color:#505050; text-decoration:none; font-size:15px; float:right;}
ul#leftcol li a.active,ul#leftcol li a:hover{color:#89b060;}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `clear:right;` from the following

```
ul#leftcol li{float:right;margin-bottom:14px; list-style:none; list-style-image:none; text-align:right; line-height:1.3; }
```

Comment: @JChase11 ... I was wrong with my first answer.  But if you remove `clear:right;` from the following `ul#leftcol li` in css.  It will fix IE 7 and not effect any other browser.

Comment: thanks, weird that IE7 clears each word instead of the entire li element

Comment: Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
ul#leftcol li a {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You could also give you li elements a fixed width.

Or maybe some display property as well like `display: inline;`